# How to create static library for iOS without making all symbols public

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa, static-libraries

This question has been asked before, but digging into the documentation for the various development tools it seems like this *is* possible, just not obvious.

Motivation:
  Making a static library for use by other iOS developers.  Some symbols in the library will cause problems if exported so I wish to make them internal-only symbols.  With a dynamic library this is easy, just use `-exported_symbols_list` `libtool` (`ld`) argument and list the ones you want public.  `libtool` documentation will not allow this argument for static libraries.

Library has several ObjectiveC .m files that use code from each other.  Only one class in the group needs to be made public to users of the final .a static library file.

Tried `libtool -exported_symbols_list publicsymbols.exp` but that argument to `libtool` is not supported with `-static` for static libraries.

Can't make the symbols private with attributes (if that'd even work) because they are needed by the other .m files in the group.

looks like `ld` can take several .o files and link them together into a new .o file (via the `-r` argument) and it doesn't have the "dynamic only" disclaimer for the `-exported_symbols_list` argument (which could just be unclear documentation...).

just as a test I build my project with Xcode so I have all the .o files made, and then try to call `ld` on the command line, like so:

```
ld -r -x -all_load -static -arch armv6 -syslibroot {path} 
   -filelist /Users/Dad/ABCsdk/iphone-ABClib/build/ABCLib.build/Distribution-iphoneos/ABCLib-device.build/Objects-normal/armv6/ABCsdk.LinkFileList 
   -exported_symbols_list {exp file path} -o outputfile.o
```

where the {path} type things have long paths to the appropriate places in there.

but I get errors like the following:

> /usr/bin/ld_classic: /Users/Dad/ABCsdk/iphone-ABClib/build/ABCLib.build/Distribution-iphoneos/ABCLib-device.build/Objects-normal/armv6/ABCmain.o incompatible, file contains unsupported type of section 3 (_*TEXT,*_picsymbolstub4) in load command 0 (must specify "-dynamic" to be used)

so something seems wrong there...

Anyone know a clever way to make this work?  Thanks.

Comment: What kind of symbols do you need to hide?

Comment: Symbols that may conflict if they have the same sub library already linked into their application (JSONkit say).  I can, obviously, just include the JSONKit files and say to include them also if they are not already in your project, but I'd hoped for a single .h file and .a file to be added to the project for a cleaner integration.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is really not possible, I'm sorry to say.  It has to do with the way static libraries work.  A static library is little more than a bunch of object `*.o` files bundled together, but a dynamic library is a loadable binary image, just like an executable.

Suppose you have four files,

- common.c defines `common`, which is "private"
- fn1.c defines `fn1`, which calls `common`.
- fn2.c defines `fn2`, which calls `common`.
- other.c defines `other`.

**In a dynamic library,** the linker bundles everything up into one big chunk of code.  The library exports `other`, `fn1`, and `fn2`.  You have to load the entire library or none of it, but two programs can both load it without putting multiple copies in memory.  The entry point to `common` is simply missing from the symbol table — you can't call it from outside the library because the linker can't find it.

Note that an application and a shared library have essentially the same format: an application is basically a shared library that only exports one symbol, `main`.  (This is not exactly true, but close.)

**In a static library,** the linker never runs.  The files all get compiled into *.o files and put into a *.a library archive.  Internal references will be unresolved.

Suppose your application calls `fn1`.  The linker sees an unresolved call to `fn1`, and then looks through the libraries.  It finds a definition for `fn1` in fn1.o.  Then the linker notices an unresolved call to `common`, so it looks it up in common.o.  This program won't get the code from fn2.c or other.c, because it doesn't use the definitions from those files.

Static libraries are very old, and they do not have any of the features of dynamic libraries.  You can think of a static library as basically a zip file full of compiled source code, unlike a dynamic library which is linked together.  Nobody ever bothered to extend the archive format to add symbol visibility.  When you link with a static library, you get the same result as if you had added the library's source code to your program.

**The short version:** A dynamic library has one symbol table of all of the exported symbols, but none of the private symbols.  In the same way, an object file has a list of all of its `extern` symbols but none of the `static` ones.  But a static library has no symbol table, it is just an archive.  So there is no mechanism to make code private to a static library (other than defining objects `static`, but that doesn't work for Objective-C classes).

If we knew why you were trying to do this, perhaps we could give you a suggestion.  (Is it for security?  Name clashes?  All of these questions have solutions.)

Comment: I don't want to write a new answer, because you have written a great explanation here, but it seems the solution, then, would be to combine all source files into one file that is compiled as a single unit. (Automatically, not manually.) The SQLite project does something like this.

Comment: Fair enough, so even if he could hide other symbols (functions, constants) the class names would still be exposed, so there's no point.

Comment: thanks @dietrich, that's about what I figured. I had hoped there might be a clever solution I'd missed, but alas it appears not :)  The other option I've considered would be to rename all the objective C classes and so on to make sure they will not conflict.

Comment: @Dad I've seen that approach for Objective C. For instance, Google Protocol Buffers for iOS lets you specify a prefix that is applied to all Objective C classes it generates so they don't conflict.

Answer (score 5):

This *is* possible! As Dietrich said, all exported symbols in `.o` files in a static library are public, and if a file needs to refer to a symbol in another `.o` file it needs to be exported from that file (and therefore public). But there's an easy workaround - pre-link all of your `.o` files into a single one. Then you only need to export the public symbols.

This is apparently called "Single Object Prelinking", and there's an option to do it in XCode that treert mentioned. But you can do it with just standard command line tools (example repo [here](https://github.com/hds/sop-example)):

Check it out (this is on Mac).

First lets create some test files

```
$ cat private.c
int internal_private_function() {
    return 5;
}
$ cat public.c
extern int internal_private_function();

int public_function() {
    return internal_private_function();
}
```

Compile them

```
$ clang -c private.c -o private.o
$ clang -c public.c -o public.o
```

Add them to a static library (it's basically a zip file, but in a decades old format).

```
$ ar -r libeverything_public.a public.o private.o
```

Check what symbols are in it.

```
$ objdump -t libeverything_public.a

libeverything_public.a(private.o):  file format Mach-O 64-bit x86-64

SYMBOL TABLE:
0000000000000000 g     F __TEXT,__text _internal_private_function

libeverything_public.a(public.o):   file format Mach-O 64-bit x86-64

SYMBOL TABLE:
0000000000000000 g     F __TEXT,__text _public_function
0000000000000000         *UND* _internal_private_function
```

Ok as you can see both functions are visible, and both symbols are `g` which means global.

Now lets prelink into a single file and then put that on its own in a static library.

```
$ ld -r -o prelinked.o private.o public.o
$ ar -r libeverything_public_prelinked.a prelinked.o
$ objdump -t libeverything_public_prelinked.a

libeverything_public_prelinked.a(prelinked.o):  file format Mach-O 64-bit x86-64

SYMBOL TABLE:
0000000000000020 l     O __TEXT,__eh_frame EH_Frame1
0000000000000038 l     O __TEXT,__eh_frame func.eh
0000000000000060 l     O __TEXT,__eh_frame EH_Frame1
0000000000000078 l     O __TEXT,__eh_frame func.eh
0000000000000000 g     F __TEXT,__text _internal_private_function
0000000000000010 g     F __TEXT,__text _public_function
```

Similar result - they're in one file but both still present and global. Finally let's filter them out (this is Mac specific). We need a list of symbols to export:

```
$ cat exported_symbols_osx.lds
_public_function
```

Then use the `-exported_symbols_list` option.

```
$ ld -r -exported_symbols_list exported_symbols_osx.lds -o prelinked_filtered.o private.o public.o
$ ar -r libfiltered_prelinked.a prelinked_filtered.o
ar: creating archive libfiltered_prelinked.a
$ objdump -t libfiltered_prelinked.a

libfiltered_prelinked.a(prelinked_filtered.o):  file format Mach-O 64-bit x86-64

SYMBOL TABLE:
0000000000000000 l     F __TEXT,__text _internal_private_function
0000000000000020 l     O __TEXT,__eh_frame EH_Frame1
0000000000000038 l     O __TEXT,__eh_frame func.eh
0000000000000060 l     O __TEXT,__eh_frame EH_Frame1
0000000000000078 l     O __TEXT,__eh_frame func.eh
0000000000000010 g     F __TEXT,__text _public_function
```

Tada! `_internal_private_function` is now a local symbol. You can add the `-x` option (or alternatively run `strip -x`) to change the name to a random meaningless value (here `l001`).

```
$ ld -r -x -exported_symbols_list exported_symbols_osx.lds -o prelinked_filtered.o private.o public.o
$ objdump -t prelinked_filtered.o

prelinked_filtered.o:   file format Mach-O 64-bit x86-64

SYMBOL TABLE:
0000000000000000 l     F __TEXT,__text l001
0000000000000020 l     O __TEXT,__eh_frame EH_Frame1
0000000000000038 l     O __TEXT,__eh_frame func.eh
0000000000000060 l     O __TEXT,__eh_frame EH_Frame1
0000000000000078 l     O __TEXT,__eh_frame func.eh
0000000000000010 g     F __TEXT,__text _public_function
```

Here's what Apple's linker has to say about `-x`:

> Do not put non-global symbols in the output file's symbol table. Non-global symbols are useful when debugging and getting symbol names in back traces, but are not used at runtime. If -x is used with -r non-global symbol names are not removed, but instead replaced with a unique, dummy name that will be automatically removed when linked into a final linked image.  This allows dead code stripping, which uses symbols to break up code and data, to work properly and provides the security of having source symbol names removed.

All of this is the same on Linux except `-exported_symbols_list`. On Linux I think you have to use `--version-script` with a file like this:

```
V0 {
  global:
    _public_function;
  local:
    *;
};
```

But I haven't tested this yet. Both this file and the `exported_symbols_list` files support wildcards.

Comment: My small contribution. `-exported_symbols_list` and `--version-script` support wildcards, yes. But first one may work only with mangled symbols. i.e. for class `my::nms::Foo` wildcards gonna be something like  `*2my3nms3Foo*`. While second one is more flexible and for mentioned class it should be:

{
global:
    extern "C++"  {
       my::nms::Foo*;
    };
local:
    *;
};

Comment: Nice explanation! We are using a 3rd party binary that does this, and I found out that the single-object static lib increases the app size vs a multiple object static lib. I noticed that the single-object has now has `no dead strip` in some symbols (`nm -m binary_file | grep 'no dead strip'`), my guess is that the linker isn't removing those causing the size increment, have you seen this side effect using this approach? here is the GH issue if you would like to look further https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/62671

Answer (score 3):

XCode BuildSetting can do this!
1. Set `Perform Single-Object Prelink` to `YES`
2. Set `Exported Symbols File` to `path_for_symbols_file`

maybe you should remove `-static`, `-exported_symbols_list` can not work static lib, but can take effect on object file.