# How to use LLVM-objcopy rename symbols in IOS ARM64

Tags: ios, c, llvm, objcopy

I got symbol collision problems when compiling IOS APP.
I have already read solutions like [changing names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40366419/change-subroutine-names-at-build-time-to-avoid-collisions-in-xcode/42016128#42016128), [using libtool(ld)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6894214/how-to-create-static-library-for-ios-without-making-all-symbols-public).
And I have tried several schemes:

1. Use the command
   ld -arch arm64 -r libMyOrig.a -o libMyNew.a -alias_list symbols_old_new.dat

   The file symbols_old_new.dat is just like:
   _funcA1 _NewName_funcA1
   _funcA2 _NewName_funcA2
   _funcA3 _NewName_funcA3

   Checking libMyNew.a with command "nm -nm libMyNew.a", I found _funcA1 _funcA2 _funcA3 were become none-external symbols and _NewName_funcA1 _NewName_funcA2 _NewName_funcA3 were external symbols.
   After these steps, I can successfully build my app, but it got crashed when running. Maybe making symbols none-external is not good enough.
2. Compile LLVM(objcopy x86_64) on MacOS
   Use command objcopy --redefine-syms symbols_old_new.dat libMyOrig.a -o libMyNew.a
   When compiling app I got warning massage like "unknown-unsupported file format ( 0x21 0x3C 0x61 0x72 0x63 0x68 0x3E 0x0A 0x5F 0x5F 0x2E 0x53 0x59 0x4D 0x44 0x45 )"

   I thought maybe I shouldn't use the x86_64-objcopy. So I cross-compiled an ARM64-LLVM.
   Sadly, my MacOS is x86_64 and I don't know how to run the command ARM64-LLVM-objcopy.

I'm stuck here.
Does anyone know a clever way to make this right? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, have you found a solution to this? I'm going through the same issue right now.